# Mongodb: How to find all docs that a specific text is not in their specific field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Suppose we have this array of docs:

```
[ {name: 'john'},{name: 'joy'},{name: 'martin'},{name: 'tom'},{name: 'eli'}]
```

and we want to find all docs that their `name` field does not include 'm' char.
I tried using Mongoose in an Express.js app:

```
Collection.find({name:{$regex:{$not:'m'}}})
```

and obviously did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for inverting the regex match result, not the character set, so put the $not outside the $regex:

```
Collection.find({name:{$not:{$regex:'m'}}})
```

Comment: did that before and did not work

Comment: I replaced $not and $regex and it threw an error after working a few times

Comment: it cannot be %100 trusted i guess

Comment: @Pouria  Would you show a `name` value where this answer does not work?

Comment: i found the error just now:  it says "$not cannot have a regex"

Comment: i tried `Collection.find({name:{$not:{$regex:'m'}}})` and it worked once and then it threw the error mentioned above

Comment: @Pouria  There must be some other problem.  Check out this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u7OKzjWMh9T).  It works every time you click `>run`.

Comment: `Collection.find({name:{$not:{$regex:/m/}}})` works a bit better